# Не получается удаление из MySQL с помощью Ajax запроса

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, bootstrap

В чем проблема?

index.php

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" id="deleteuser">
              Удалить(<?php echo $ids = $row->id ?>)
            </button>
          <script>
            $('#deleteuser').click(function () {
              var ids = '<?php echo $row->id?>';
              $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax/deleteuser.php',
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                data: {'ids' : ids},
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(data) {
                  if(data == 'Готово')
                    $('#deleteuser').text('Удалено');
                }
              });
            });
</script>
```

deleteuser.php

```
<?php
$ids = $_POST['ids'];

require_once 'connect.php';

$sql = 'DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE `id` = :ids';
$query = $pdo->query($sql);
$query->execute();

echo 'Готово';
 ?>
```

Comment: А какая ошибка? Что в $ids в deleteuser.php и что в $row->id в index.php?

Comment: а какая ошибка?

Comment: Ничего не происходит после клика, ожидается удаление из БД строки

Comment: @nilecrocodile, в $ids я записывал id строки из БД, в $row еще другие данные, но я выбираю id. $row->id - получаем id записи, а в $ids я просто записывал это значение

Comment: Почитайте мануальчик и почувствуйте разницу между `query` и `execute`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А так?

```
$sql = 'DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE `id` = :ids';
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':ids', $ids, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: Это вот похоже на правду. Кстати `:` в `bindParam` можно опускать.